# LLDB not able to debug application

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, lldb

I currently want to debug my application using the LLDB debugger. I am successfully able to run code in my application if I set a breakpoint on my iPhone app and when I click `build and run`. The problem is if I start my application without Xcode and attach the debugger to my iOS application. Doing it this way means I cannot debug my application.

When I do `build and run` from Xcode along with a breakpoint and run the LLDB command `list`. I can see that it is debugging the `GameViewController.swift` file, however when I attach the debugger to my app after running it normally, the LLDB debugger is now in the AppDelegate file.

How would I get the LLDB debugger to debug the file `GameViewController.swift` instead of `AppDelegate,swift` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bear in mind that the debugger is attached to your entire application, not to a particular file.

When you attach to the program, it stops *wherever* the program happens to be; and if the program is idling, that will be in the `AppDelegate` more times than not.

To get it to list code in another file, you can use the `list` command, e.g. by using:

```
list GameViewController.swift:10
```

It lists the file GameViewController.swift, from line `10`, for `10` lines.

You can add in a breakpoint for a method in GameViewController, e.g. for a method called `onClick` by doing:

```
breakpoint set --file GameViewController.swift -n onClick
```

or a line using:

```
breakpoint set --file GameViewController.swift -l 998
```

and then continuing, until it stops in the relevant piece of code.

Comment: Thank you for telling me why this happens. How would I be able to access variables  and functions in the game `GameViewController.swift`? Thats another thing I wanted to know. Also when making the breakpoint, the app would never stop at that point since it has already gone past it.

Comment: If you're using XCode itself, then just click on the file in the project navigator and examine the code there. Put in breakpoints and wait for the code to stop in the relevant piece of code, then examine the variable through the variable examination window. Until you have a reference to an *instance* of the `GameViewController` class, you won't be able to see the values of properties/variables of the class and breaking in a method of the class is an easy way of getting that reference.

Comment: I wanted to run my application normally first then run the debugger. Also when I tried running code from `GameViewController`, it was after the app was launched, meaning all the code had been executed.

Comment: I have found a way to fix this issue for my current project. There is a function that is run every time the phone gets rotated. I have added a breakpoint there, that way I am inside the `GameViewController.swift` file

Comment: I was going to comment that you would need something like that to get it to break; otherwise you would need to retain a reference to the controller somewhere that you could easily examine from the debugger.

Comment: So you mean the only way to access code in a certain file is to have a function that gets called?

Comment: The file only contains the specification of what is in an object (everything within the `class ... {}` block is what makes up the object). It, in itself, doesn't have anything. When you create an instance of an class, this is the thing that actually has the data. When you call a routine in the class, it gets a reference to this instance, which is how you can see the data at that point. If you don't have a reference to the instance, then you have no data to examine. You can look at the code, but unless you have the state that goes along with it (the `self`) you can't examine the data.